# selecting specific line numbers

Tags: awk

I have a file Which contain 50,000 lines of floating values. I need to select only data every 100 lines. Is there any command available in awk programming?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

To print lines which are numbered 100, 200, 300... you can do:

```
awk 'NR%100==0' inputfile
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/CifTG)

Comment: Same idea: `awk '!(NR%100)' file`

Comment: Thanks for the code. But if I run this code I don't get the first line.How if I want to include the first line?

Answer (score 1):

Alternative, `sed` solution:

```
sed -n '100~100p' file
```

More generally, the expression `A~Kp` means print every Kth line starting with line A.